# How to install Chrome Dev?

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, flash, chromium

No!!! I want to download **chrome dev** to get dev version of **libpepperflash or whatever it is called now** and add it to **chromium**.

Also **DO pre "stable" channels add repository auto?***

If not what is the repository?

Comment: https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/eula_dev.html?dl=unstable_i386_deb

if amd64 then replace i386 with amd64

Comment: You don't need to download Chrome to get pepper flash. There is a PPA (of which I don't have the link handy) which gives you pepper flash. Google for "pepper flash in chromium".

Comment: can you post the latest one though from the latest chrome build?Im still looking but currently no results for that

Comment: You technically don't need the latest one; you just need Pepper Flash.

Comment: New verisons are almost always better.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of how to install chrome dev since it's asking about how to put the plug-in from the dev branch in to chromium.  That said, if a person is that on about testing the pepper plug-in, I would thing "TO THE GOOGLES" would be in their vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning**
You want to install an edge plug-in.  This answer is technically correct, but it will, in all probability, break packages that auto-install the pepper plug-in in chromium.  So, use at the cost of putting your system in an inconsistent state.

Of course I assume you installed chromuim from [dev channel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel)

to install libpepperflash on chromium, open your terminal and write the following:

```
chromium-browser --ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome*/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=11.3.31.323
```

To always have the correct Flash Player version in Chromium:

open your profile

```
vi  ~/.profile
```

add this to the end:

```
export PEPPER_FLASH_VERSION=$(grep '"version":' /opt/google/chrome*/PepperFlash/manifest.json| grep -Po '(?<=version": ")(?:\d|\.)*')
```

Now open chromium settings:

```
sudo vi /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

And replace CHROMIUM_FLAGS="" with the following:

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome*/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=$PEPPER_FLASH_VERSION"
```

Comment: I would upvote you but there are stupid reputation limits on this site.(need 15 rep to upvote) I installed chrome dev and copied libpepflashplayer.so already to chromium already though.Im wondering why you got downvoted

Comment: This answer doesn't state that you need to install Google Chrome first (which is a bad solution in my opinion just to use Chromium), nor is it entirely dynamic when Chrome is updated.

Comment: @saiarcot895 this is what I wanted though to use the latest ppflash in latest chromium.And there is no better way?

Comment: @saiarcot895 review the edit please.

Comment: @PriceSave I added the support for latest version

Comment: Technically, Google Chrome, not Chromium, but sure. I removed my downvote.

Comment: @PriceSave if you have tried the answer and worked for you please mark it as answer

Comment: @kamil Ill try it as soon as I get chromium installed again but unfortunately when i download from official site I get chrome not chromium!Why is that?

Comment: If it were my question, I would accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Pepper Flash is available through a PPA for Precise, Quantal, Saucy, and Trusty (although Trusty will have this package in the default repos).

See https://launchpad.net/~skunk/+archive/pepper-flash for installation instructions.

Short version of the instructions:

The following adds the PPA and installs the Pepper Flash Player:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer
```

Now, you need to tell Chromium to use this version of the Flash Player. To do that, open up /etc/chromium-browser/default (something like `sudo nano /etc/chromium-browser/default or sudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default`), and on a new line at the end of the file, add the following line:

```
 /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh
```

Save and close the file, and run Chromium as normal. If you go to about:plugins, you should see it's using Flash 12.x.x.xx.

Comment: Does this install the latest ppflash or the one from stable chrome?

Comment: The one from stable Google Chrome.

Comment: I just discovered you maintain chromium repo!No offense but I want to donwload latest chromium and the official chromium website dwnloads me chrome instead of chromium! So do you always have the latest version?

Comment: Yes. Well, I might be a day behind, like right now. I'll be uploading the new version in the next hour, and it should be available in about 5 hours.

Comment: Wonderful! Do you know why the site http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel gives me chrome not chromium?

Comment: The title says "Chrome Release Channels", not Chromium. Part of the reason might be Chromium doesn't have any auto-updating feature, and so it might be too much work to keep changing the download link. Note that there are pre-compiled Chromium packages available, but it doesn't look like they make any distinction between dev, beta, and stable.